# How to invoke an Azure Devops task from PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a number of subfolders in a repository that all contain an Azure ARM template (folder name = resource group).

I'm trying to iterate each folder and then create a pipeline artifact from contents of that folder.

How do I invoke a devops task from PowerShell script? The script below gives an error saying that `PublishPipelineArtifact` task is not found.

```
foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name))
{
    Write-Host "Processing folder $($folder.Name)..."

    Write-Host "##vso[task.PublishPipelineArtifact targetPath=$folder;artifactName=$($folder.Name);]"

    Write-Host "Published artifact $($folder.Name)..."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it's possible with "Logging commands". See https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

For example this script packages all folders as artifacts:

```
Write-Host ("Working folder is {0}" -f $($env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY))

foreach ($folder in (Get-ChildItem -Path $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object Name))
{
    Write-Host "Processing folder $($folder.Name)..."

    $folderPath = $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY + "\" + $folder.Name
    $artifactFolder = $env:BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY + "\" + $folder.Name
    $pathToZip = $artifactFolder + "\" + $folder.Name + ".zip"

    Write-Host "Creating archive to " + $artifactFolder

    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $artifactFolder

    $compress = @{
        Path = $($folderPath) + "\*"
        CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
        DestinationPath = $pathToZip
    }
    Compress-Archive @compress

    Write-Host "##vso[artifact.upload containerfolder=$($folder.Name);artifactname=$($folder.Name)_drop;]$pathToZip"

    Write-Host "Published artifact $($folder.Name)..."
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I have been trying using a yaml each loop (as in the answer from @Cece Dong) but if the list of folders to publish is generated dynamically at run time it is not possible de to the expansion of the parameter in the expression occurring before the list is generated leading to a "Expected sequence or mapping" error on parsing the pipeline

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported to invoke a devops task from PowerShell script, you could try `each` function to loop the `PublishPipelineArtifact` task:

```
parameters:
- name: param
  type: object
  default:
  - folder1
  - folder2

 
steps:
  - ${{ each p in parameters.param }}:
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)' 
          artifactName: '${{ p }}'
```